# Linux nohup file got removed but directory still filling

Tags: linux

My linux process filling up drive quickly so i did rm -rf to nohup file and learned later that since the process is not killed and restarted, application will keep using nohup file to append the console logs. What should i do now? I cannot kill and restart process and at the same time i have to free up the drive.

Comment: then kill the process or delete something else on the same partition.

Comment: Thats not an option

Comment: It's unfortunate that you already deleted the file. The correct way of handling it is truncating the file. If you can manage to undelete the file then you can truncate it. But there's no interface to undelete a file nor an interface to create a file in a known inode. You just shot yourself in the foot. Don't worry, the process is bound to die when you run out of space, then you can restart it when it's dead.

Comment: Here's an untested solution. `pid=$(pgrep processname); cd /proc/$pid/fd; cat /dev/null > fdofdeletedfile`. If you can't figure out the file descriptor of the deleted file, you can use `lsof` to find it.

Comment: Thanks will give it a shot!! Appreciate your help